# Custom font specifiers in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I would like to add a new font specifier, so that I can for example use `C-c C-f C-a` to insert `\textcolour{blue}{*}`
Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Customize the variable `LaTeX-font-list` with <kbd>M-x customize-variable RET LaTeX-font-list RET</kbd>.

Note that <kbd>C-a</kbd> is already preset.  You can either change that entry or pick another key for your command.  Then add `\textcolour{blue}{` as `Prefix` and `}` as `Suffix`, and hit `Apply and Save`.

In order to make a choice for a key, these are the ones preset by AUCTeX (next release tracking changes in LaTeX kernel 2020-02-02):

```lisp
(defcustom LaTeX-font-list
  '((?\C-a ""              ""  "\\mathcal{"    "}")
    (?\C-b "\\textbf{"     "}" "\\mathbf{"     "}")
    (?\C-c "\\textsc{"     "}")
    (?\C-e "\\emph{"       "}")
    (?\C-f "\\textsf{"     "}" "\\mathsf{"     "}")
    (?\C-i "\\textit{"     "}" "\\mathit{"     "}")
    (?\C-l "\\textulc{"    "}")
    (?\C-m "\\textmd{"     "}")
    (?\C-n "\\textnormal{" "}" "\\mathnormal{" "}")
    (?\C-r "\\textrm{"     "}" "\\mathrm{"     "}")
    (?\C-s "\\textsl{"     "}" "\\mathbb{"     "}")
    (?\C-t "\\texttt{"     "}" "\\mathtt{"     "}")
    (?\C-u "\\textup{"     "}")
    (?\C-w "\\textsw{"     "}")
    (?\C-d "" "" t))
    ...
```

---

In order to set the chosen character in the customize buffer, you have to follow [this guideline](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Ctl_002dChar-Syntax.html#Ctl_002dChar-Syntax):

> #### 2.3.3.3 Control-Character Syntax
>
> Control characters can be represented using yet another read syntax.
>   This consists of a question mark followed by a backslash, caret, and
>   the corresponding non-control character, in either upper or lower
>   case. For example, both `?\^I` and `?\^i` are valid read syntax for
>   the character <kbd>C-i</kbd>, the character whose value is 9.
>
> Instead of the `^`, you can use `C-`; thus, `?\C-i` is equivalent to `?\^I` and to `?\^i`:
>   `?\^I ⇒ 9     ?\C-I ⇒ 9`

And don't be worry about the numbers you see in your init file.  Again from the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Type.html#Character-Type):

> #### 2.3.3 Character Type
>
> A character in Emacs Lisp is nothing more than an integer. In other
>   words, characters are represented by their character codes. For
>   example, the character A is represented as the integer 65.

Comment: Thanks! This worked but there's a couple of things I still don't understand. First, after `M-x customize-variable RET LaTeX-font-list RET` I get the Easy Customization tool, from which I can edit the variable entries. How do I enter values for keys in this tool? The built-in ones appear as e.g. `^A` (in blue), but if I just write e.g. `^J` in my new entry it doesn't accept it. Second, after saving in Easy Customization, it creates an entry in my `.emacs` file, which instead of having e.g. `?\C-a` as your answer, just shows numbers for the key (e.g. `1` for `C-a`) What do these map to?

Comment: @SuperNano - See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

After `M-x customize-variable RET LaTeX-font-list RET`:

You should see that most of the `Key` field defined by AUCTeX is hardly invisible(depends on your color theme), this
is because the key here are shown **as it is**, so things like `C-a` are
invisible. So, you have to **insert the non-graphical char (such as control-c)**
yourself in the `customize` buffer. Say you wanna bind `C-c C-f C-x` to
inserting `aaa[your text]bbb` then try:

1. Press the `INS` button to insert a new entry
2. In the `Prefix` field, type： `aaa`
3. In the `Suffix` field, type： `bbb`
4. In the `Key` field, type : `C-q C-x` (this will insert a literal `C-x` into
   the buffer, `C-q` stands for `(quoted-insert)`)
5. Click `Apply And Save` at the top.
6. Back in your `.tex` file, `M-x TeX-normal-mode` to take that into effect (this should load the style hooks and everything.).

Note: You cannot fill emacs-lisp expression in the these fields.

In fact it's easier (and safer) to set `Key` field to something like `x`, this
will bind your `PREFIX[your text]SUFFIX` pair to key `C-c C-f x`.

Or, if you prefer lisp:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-font-list '(?a "\\myFontA{" "}"))
;;bind to C-c C-f a
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-font-list '(?b "\\myFontB{" "}"))   
;;bind to C-c C-f b

;;Sometimes you need the following. This reload the 'LaTeX-font-list
;; (TeX-normal-mode)
```